# Undersanding Django's get_absolute_url using reverse

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to write an app that, among other things, will generate a list of dogs that are available for adoption.

At the moment when I try to generate that list I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'dog' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'dog_id': 3, 'name': 'Rex'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ForeverHomes/Dog/(?P<dog_id>\\d+)/(P?<name>[A-Za-z ]+)']
```

Which is being raise when Django tries to get the absolute url via:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('ForeverHomes:dog',
                   kwargs={"dog_id": self.dog_id,
                           "name": self.name},
                    current_app="ForeverHomes")
```

The pattern that it's trying to match is the correct pattern, but what I don't understand is how my `Dog` object is ever meant to match to a regular expression. My `Dog` objects all have a `dog_id` and a `name`, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "how my Dog object is ever meant to match to a regular expression".

Your problem is simply that you have a malformed regex: the `?` and the `P` are the wrong way round in the `name` group.

Comment: Thank you. I've been pouring over examples trying to figure out what I was missing, but I was looking in entirely the wrong spot.